# Drupal 6: only displaying select vocabularies?

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

I use two vocabularies, one for tags and one which determines where a view will be displayed. Can anyone tell me how I could output the terms of my former category while hiding the ones in my latter category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the row style of your view is "Fields", add a "Taxonomy: All terms" field to your view. On that field's settings form, you will see a "Limit terms by vocabulary" checkbox. Select it and choose the vocabulary you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to display the terms of a vocabulary. The views module is great for this. You can create a view showing terms and select only to show the ones in the vocabulary of your choice.

Comment: Oooh sorry, don't think I worded my question properly... what I meant is that I'm creating views with the title, a thumbnail and a teaser and I'd like to output tags (but only tags and not other vocabularies) over each item in the view... do you know how I could do that? Thanks so much!